# how to create binary XML

Tags: xml, binary

hi all
can you tell me how to create a binary XML ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<list>
    <item>images10.gif</item>
    <item>images19.gif</item>
    <item>images18.gif</item>
    <item>images17.gif</item>
    <item>images16.gif</item>
</list>
```

how to covert this to BXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few [competing standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML). If you don't want to complicate things, just use a well defined compression algorithm, like zip, 7zip, gzip, rar or something else.

If you wanted to include *content* from `images` files, then you have to parse your xml and put those files' data in your xml file. Just be sure to escape that data with [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).